# react-google-charts with spreadsheets does'nt work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-google-charts

I'm facing a problem where I can't render a google chart with the library react-google-charts. I looked its documentation and its examples with spreadsheets doesn't work also.

```
import React from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";

export function App() {
  return (
    <Chart
      chartType="ScatterChart"
      spreadSheetUrl="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jN0iw0usssnsG1_oi-NXtuKfsUsGme09GsFidbqxFYA/edit#gid=0"
      options={{
        hAxis: {
          format: "short",
        },
        vAxis: {
          format: "decimal",
        },
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

The code above is an example of the react-google-charts documentation. An error saying "table has no column" is showed.

Trying to use it, I reached in a state where no error is returned but the google chart still isn't rendered.

The code below is the chart I trying to render from a test spreadsheet.

```
<Chart
    chartPackages={['corechart']}
    chartVersion='current'
    chartType="LineChart"
    loader={<>Loading</>}                       spreadSheetUrl="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YkiUyz7O8TPhl_4kKXT33yL4wjsRMviLOkcrarOhPxI"
    spreadSheetQueryParameters={{
        headers: 3,
        query: 'SELECT *',
        sheet: 'teste'
    }}
/>
```

Every chart created from a spreadsheet makes a network request and this it's not happening. I pass a prop called loader which tells to use this markup when loading the chart. This is the only thing rendered for now. Without it, the result is nothing. Blank markup.

I'm using React with Next.js in this project.

I tried to render a google chart with spreadsheets. I expect to see a chart rendered. But, the result is nothing. There is no response.